# How to compile Full .NET along with NETStandard project

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, asp.net-web-api2, .net-5

I have Full .NET 4.7.2 Web API project. This is existing project. On CI server I am building this project using MSBuild version `15.6.85.37198` from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild` folder

I added another `NETStandard2` library project that has common code. The Web API 2 project now has a project reference to this NETStandard2 project.

Also updated The Web Api's config as

```
<system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.7.2" debug="true">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />
```

On local machine I am using VS 2019 and both projects are compiling.

On CI server I have installed new `NET 5` SDK. I am building Web Project as

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild MyApi.csproj /p:Configuration=Release

Its throwing error

> error : Version 5.0.101 of the .NET Core SDK requires at least version
> 16.8.0 of MSBuild. The current available version of MSBuild is 15.6.85.37198. Change the .NET Core SDK specified in global.json to an older version that requires the MSBuild version currently available.

The error is self explanatory. Since web api is referencing NetStandard I have to install MSbuild 16*

However, from [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/walkthrough-using-msbuild?view=vs-2019)

> To install MSBuild on a system that doesn't have Visual Studio, go to
> Visual Studio downloads and scroll down to All Downloads, then expand
> Tools for Visual Studio 2019. Install Build Tools for Visual Studio
> 2019, which includes MSBuild, or install the .NET Core SDK.

the last part says `or install the .NET Core SDK.`

**Questions**
1> I have installed NET5 SDK on CI server, Does that also installs MSbuild 16.*, if yes which location?
2> Where is global.json file located?

Answer (score 0):

You should note that `.NET5` is only available for at least `VS2019 16.8` and it cannot work with **VS2017** and **MSBuild 15.x**. See the [Visual Studio support of Net5.0](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0).

`NET 5.0` is dontet cli tool while `MSBuild 16.x` is build tool for VS, they are two different tools that do not interfere with each other.

To use it, you should download [Build Tool for VS2019](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=16) and remember to check the Net Core build tool workload, .Net Desktop Build tool workload and any other build workloads you used.

Or you have to check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json?tabs=netcore2x) to use a lower Net Core SDK which supports `msbuild 15.6`(like Net Core `2.1.201`).

**Note**: change `global.json` file is not a good choice and it changes your internal project and it is at risk. Obviously, changing external build tools is more secure and compliant.

**Update 1**

Install VS2019 IDE on the Build server which solves the issue.

Comment: I resolved the issue by installing VS 2019 on the build server. (installing only build tools for 2019 + Net Core Build tool did not work for me)

Comment: And also you want to build net472 project and also check net desktop build tool and if you use to use other tools integrated with VS2019, you have to install VS2019 IDE.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution and be glad to know that you have solved the issue. To help improve the ticket, I have added your workaround into the answer and you could mark the answer to help other community members search and handle similar issues. And it is kind of you to do that. Have a nice day!